# Make smooth transform rotate on hover

Tags: html, css

After hover the cursor on one menu item , if you move the cursor slightly before the transform get complete , the transform will start again. it will happen again  and again when you shake you move little bit on the menu item . 
How can I overcome this issue?

```
<ul id="menu-1">
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a></li>
</ul>

ul#menu-1 {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    width:100%
}
ul#menu-1 li{
  background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    min-width: 15.87%;
    animation: elmtoFront 1.2s linear normal forwards;
}

ul#menu-1 li a {
    display:block;
color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#menu-1 li a:hover{
    transition: 1.2s ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;    
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    animation:elmtoBack 1.2s linear normal forwards;
}
@keyframes elmtoBack {  
  0% {z-index:0;}
  100% {z-index:1;}
}
@keyframes elmtoFront {
  0% {z-index:1;}
  100% {z-index:0;}
}
```

FYI : https://jsfiddle.net/anushkakrajasingha/bpp48a15/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
ul#menu-1 li a:hover{
```

to this

```
ul#menu-1 li:hover a{
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpp48a15/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Give the property an alternative selection like below

change `ul#menu-1 li a:hover` to `ul#menu-1 li:hover a`

```
ul#menu-1 li:hover a{
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;    
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    animation:elmtoBack 1.2s linear normal forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to concentrate on the solution because that has been described in the other answers already but they lack an explanation on why it is happening this way. So, I will explain that bit.

**Reason:**

It is because you are using a `rotateY` transform on the `a` element. When such a transform is used, the boundaries of the element gets smaller and smaller as the element is rotating. So, when we move the cursor as the transformation is going on, the chances are high that we are actually **hovering out** of the element and then back in to the element. This, as you would know would re-trigger the `hover` selector to get applied and thus re-start the transform.

For example, have a look at the below snippet and see how the borders of the element shrink as the transformation is happening. The restart effect will be pronounced as you hover-in from the edges of the box because then the cursor quickly goes out of the box as it is shrinking in size.

```css
.transformed {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.transformed:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
]
```

```html
<div class='transformed'>Some content</div>
```

**Solution:**

As already described in the other answers, put the `:hover` on the `li` and style the `a` when the `li` is hovered on. When this is done, the `li` boundaries never change and so the cursor position never actually goes outside of the element. So there is no re-trigger of the `:hover` selector and no restart.

```css
ul#menu-1 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%
}
ul#menu-1 li {
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  min-width: 15.87%;
  animation: elmtoFront 1.2s linear normal forwards;
}
ul#menu-1 li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu-1 li:hover a {
  transition: 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  animation: elmtoBack 1.2s linear normal forwards;
}
@keyframes elmtoBack {
  0% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes elmtoFront {
  0% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-1">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```